# $.post jquery data posting

Tags: php, jquery

My Jquery code for clicking the button in the form is:

```
    $('#save1').on('click',function()
           {
       $.post('n.php',{'name': $('name').val(),'rollno': $('rollno').val(), 'mobile': $('mobile').val(), 'fblink': $('fblink').val(), 'linkedin': $('linkedin').val(),'skypelink': $('skypelink').val()},function(data) {
           if(data=='success') {
               $('#myModal').modal('show');

           }
       });
     return false;
    });

  <form class="form-horizontal" action='n.php' method="POST">
```

Here the data is not getting posted though the alert box is popping

My php file n.php is:

```
 <?php
 $n=$_POST['name'];
 $r=$_POST['rollno'];
 $m=$_POST['mobile'];
 $f=$_POST['fblink'];
 $l=$_POST['linkedin'];
 $s=$_POST['skypelink'];
 $mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','root','password','user_details');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
 exit();
 }
$q=$mysqli->query("insert into store(Name,RollNo,MobileNo,FacebookLink,LinkedinLink,SkypeLink) values('$n','$r','$m','$f','$l','$s')");
 $response='success';
 echo $response;
 ?>
```

But when I remove return false from the click event function the data is stored in the database. Please help me in correcting the code so that when the user clicks the button the alert box is popped and the form values are stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Jquery code

from

```
 $('#save1').on('click',function()
       {
   $.post('n.php',{'name': $('name').val(),'rollno': $('rollno').val(), 'mobile': $('mobile').val(), 'fblink': $('fblink').val(), 'linkedin': $('linkedin').val(),'skypelink': $('skypelink').val()},function(data) {
       if(data=='success') {
           $('#myModal').modal('show');

       }
   });
 return false;
});
```

to

```
$('#save1').on('click',function()
       {
   $.post('n.php',{'name': $('#name').val(),'rollno': $('#rollno').val(), 'mobile': $('#mobile').val(), 'fblink': $('#fblink').val(), 'linkedin': $('#linkedin').val(),'skypelink': $('#skypelink').val()},function(data) {
       if(data=='success') {
           $('#myModal').modal('show');

       }
   });
 return false;
});
```

always

> use a # for getting element by id
>
> use a . for getting element by class

Comment: if my answer resolves your problem mark it as verified

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, you are widely leaving your application open for MySQL injection with the way you are handling your data.

You should look into PDO, and creating prepared statements for Database manipulation.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: In mysqli how can we prevent sql injection?

Comment: You should use PDO instead of MySQLi. Read this: https://phpbestpractices.org/ and go to PHP and MySQL. PDO is just a different API - implemented the same way you would implement MySQLi - but if you use stored procedures (google that if you don't understand), it will clean your inputs for you to help prevent MySQL injections.